# Delphi Firemonkey OSX how to convert the following code?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

I cannot find a solution to convert the following code to run under OSX. Does anybody know how I can get a unix timestamp (UTC) under OSX?

```
function GetUnixTimestamp: int64;
var
    st: TSystemTime;
    dt: TDateTime;
    ut: int64;
begin
    dt := SystemTimeToDateTime(st);
    ut := DateTimeToUnix(dt);
    result := ut;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I am just plain stupid... the following code does exactly what I want:

```
result:=DateTimeToUnix(now,true);
```

Comment: You sure `Now` returns UTC date time :P?

Comment: No, I am not, and I think it does not of course, I misinterpreted the flag regarding UTC. So the question is still open, how do I get the unix timestamp with firemonkey and OSX as target?

Answer (score 0):

Add `System.DateUtils` to your uses clause.

Then use this code:

```
//Get the current local time
dtLocal:=Now;
//Convert to UTC
dtUTC:=TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(dtLocal);
//Convert UTC time to Unix format
dtUTCUnix:=DateTimeToUnix(dtUTC, True);
```

Note that `TTimeZone.Local` has other attributes including UTC offset, Daylight savings, etc. Use as appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @softtouch - did the answer above address your question?